# Filter nested objects in coredata using NSPredicate SUBQUERY

Tags: swift, core-data, swift5

My Data Model as follow, and my objective is to filter the Contacts belong to that Community

```
Contact<<->Account<<->Comunity
```

This is what i have done so far and im gettin is exceptions since its a wrong query.

```
let contacts = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(account, $x, SUBQUERY($x.community, $y, ANY $y.community_id == %@)).@count > 0", community_id)
```

Comment: According to your diagram, each Contact has only one Account, and each Account has only one Community.  Please confirm.  If so, no need for the subquery, just “account.community.community_id == %@“.

Comment: yes @pbasdf your order is r8 on the entities, but in this use case i need a subquery as i am doing some processing after fetching all contacts. So for that i need to fetch all the contacts related to that community

Comment: If you are fetching Contacts, then the predicate should just be “account.community.community_id == %@“.

Comment: already tried that @pbasdf and it says 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "account.community.community_id == %@).@count > 0"'

Comment: NSPredicate(format:"account.community.community_id == %@).@count > 0", community_id)

Comment: Try `NSPredicate(format:"account.community.community_id == %@", community_id)`